# CSS class finder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a requirement which sounds like kind of simple but hard to implement at least for me, so here what it is

I have a dropdown with a search field in it similar to auto complete, when a key word is typed in the search field all the class names becomes empty except the keyword items.

Now i need to get the id's of "li's" only with class names,

I am new to jquery any help is greatly appreciated here is my code

```
function selectSearchItems() {
        alert("hai");
        var origul = document.getElementById("orig_ul");
        var origlis = origul.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < origlis.length; i++) {
            alert($('ul#orig_ul li').children('li.active-result'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: "all the class names becomes empty except the keyword items" ... what does that mean?

Comment: Show us a complete example (html code?).

Comment: <li id="merch_drp_chzn_o_2402" class="" style=""></li>
<li id="merch_drp_chzn_o_2404" class="active-result" style=""></li>

Comment: If you want id's of li's, try this: `id = $('li.active-result').attr('id');`

Comment: thank you fari that helped a little, but i have two "ul" elements in my page, so i need the li elements in that particular ul with id "orig_ul"

and also I have more than one li with same class name, i need to get id's of all of them

Comment: @JagadeeshVenkata So you should use this: `id = $('ul#orig_ul li.active-result').attr('id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function selectSearchItems() {
    alert("hai");
    var origul = $("#orig_ul");
    var origlis = origul.find('li[class]');
    for (var i = 0; i < origlis.length; i++) {
        alert(origlis[i].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i specify class name here itself     
`var origlis = $(origul).find('li[class]');`

Comment: @JagadeeshVenkata Then do  `var origlis = $(origul).find('li.classThatYouWant')`

Comment: one more question how to go to the next li element with same class name because i have more than one li element with same class name

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < origlis.length; i++) {
                if (i==0) {
                    alert($('li.active-result').attr('id'));
                } else {
                    alert($('li.active-result').next().attr('id'));
                }`